# Laravel storage folder changed it's permission frequently

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

Daily (I'm not able to trace at which event like command run, cron runs ), the project's storage folder (in which all logs are written) lost its permission. Due to this login, the logout stops working.

I have to re-give permission of 777 to each time.

This happens once a day. Does anyone has solution for that?

Comment: You should **never** use 777 as permission in any folder, this is totally not secure

Comment: Seems to me the issue is not permissions but ownership. If the webserver user is the owner of the folder than 7XX should be sufficient permissions. Do you have any automatic deployment going on?

Comment: most likely indeed a user issue. You should have a permission of 770 (at most). Or in other words. Owner can do anything, the group can do anything and anyone else cannot access the folder. Might also be useful to look into the SGID (+s flag). As it will use the owners name to change the files instead of the executer.  Depends on what setup your running

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ , Okay, so which permission i should give ?

Comment: @Ken Okay, i will give it as 770 Permission and will check.

Comment: @apokryfos, Yes, I have configured Git in server and deploying using it.

Comment: @Ken 770 Permission not works. It stops whole website to stop works.

Comment: @JatinBhattPhp it will only work with 770 if the user running the webserver & git user doing the deploy are part of the same group. Looks like you need to do some user & group management on your server

Comment: If you're auto-deploying via a cron task then make sure your cron task runs as the webserver user. For apache that's `www-data` (no idea for others)

Comment: @apokryfos , I am not using cron , i am using manual GIT PULL in server . And also, storage folder is in git ignore for that.